# Create several pages from array

Tags: javascript, python, html, arrays, django

I'm developing my `Django Project` about Civil State and I have a question according to my `HTML template`.

I'm displaying a list of objects from my `BirthCertificate table` with an `HTML Array` as you can see in my script :

```
{% extends 'Base_Accueil.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

{% load bootstrap %}

        <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
        }

        th {background-color: #0083A2;}

        tr:hover td{background-color:lightslategray;}

        </style>

        <!-- Title page -->

        <h2 align="center"> <font color="#0083A2"> Consultation des tables annuelles et décennales </font></align></h2>

        <!-- Body page -->

        <br></br>
        <h4> <b><font color="#0083A2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Liste des actes de naissance </b></font></h4>

        <form method="GET" action="">
            <input type="text"  name="q1" placeholder="Entrer une année" value="{{ request.GET.q1 }}"> &nbsp;
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Rechercher">
        </form>

        <br></br>

        <table style="width:50%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Prénom</th>
                    <th>Date de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Ville de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Pays de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Date création de l'acte</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in query_naissance_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{item.id}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.lastname}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.firstname}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.birthday}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.birthcity}} </td>
                    <td> {{item.birthcountry}} </td>
                    <td>{{item.created}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I get this website page :

[image]

My question is : How I can **add some pages** from my array in order to display the list ten by ten for example ?
Which langage I have to use : `Python`, `HTML`, `Javascript` (better way isn't it ?), ... ?

It's the first time I'm making this kind of things and I don't find on StackOverFlow or somewhere else clues to do that.

Thank you so much by advance !

Comment: I have to be honest, i don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/).
You can add pages to the list view with Paginator.

Do something like this in your view:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
paginator = Paginator(query_naissance_list, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    query_naissance_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    query_naissance_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    query_naissance_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

In template add navigation:

```
    {% if query_naissance_list.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ query_naissance_list.number }} of {{ query_naissance_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if query_naissance_list.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I'm talking ! Thank you very much !