# Django pagination doesn't display all pages

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

I'm improving my `Django project` with pagination in order to display the query result page by page.
Thanks to @neverwalkaloner for helping me : [Create several pages from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091272/create-several-pages-from-array/42093076#42093076)

But I get an insoluble error. I can display the first page and it works pretty well, but when I select the next page, it doesn't display it with next results.

As you can see :

**First page**

[image]

**Second page**

[image]

This is my view :

```
@login_required
def Table_annuelle_BirthCertificate(request) :

    query_naissance = request.GET.get('q1')
    request.session['query_naissance'] = query_naissance

    if query_naissance  :
        query_naissance_list = BirthCertificate.objects.filter(created__icontains=query_naissance).order_by('lastname')
    else :
        query_naissance_list = BirthCertificate.objects.none() # == []

    paginator = Paginator(query_naissance_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        query_naissance_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        query_naissance_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        query_naissance_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "BirthCertificate":BirthCertificate,
        "query_naissance" : query_naissance,
        "query_naissance_list" : query_naissance_list,
        "PageNotAnInteger":PageNotAnInteger,
        }

    return render(request, 'annuel.html', context)
```

And my template :

```
<h4 class = "col-sm-10"> <b><font color="#0083A2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Prévisualisation de la table annuelle des naissances </b></font></h4>

<form class = "col-sm-10" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text"  name="q1" placeholder="Entrer une année" value="{{ request.GET.q1 }}"> &nbsp;
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Rechercher">
</form>

<br></br>
<br></br>

<table style="width:50%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom & prénom(s)</th>
            <th>Lieux de Naissance</th>
            <th>Date des actes</th>
            <th>Numéro de l'acte</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_naissance_list %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{item.lastname}} {{item.firstname}} </td>
            <td> {{item.birthcity}} ({{item.birthcountry.name}}) </td>
            <td> {{item.created}} <p></p> {{item.birthday}} (Naissance) </td>
            <td> {{item.id}} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% if query_naissance_list.has_previous %}
<a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.previous_page_number }}">Page précédente</a>
{% endif %}

<span class="current">
    Page {{ query_naissance_list.number }} sur {{ query_naissance_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
</span>

{% if query_naissance_list.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.next_page_number }}">Page suivante</a>
{% endif %}
```

Have you an idea ? I'm checking lot of tutorials and I don't find where I forgot something ?

Comment: It could be possible that `query_naissance_list = paginator.page(page)` within the `try` block is throwing an exception that you are not seeing

Comment: I used the @Sayse example and it works. I had to specify each time my `q1` variable to each page. I thought it was global for all pages and finally not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose the get parameter every time that specifies your queryset

```
query_naissance = request.GET.get('q1')
```

I'm not entirely sure where you get this `q1` from so you either need to include this in the get param for the anchor

```
<a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.next_page_number }}&q1={{ request.GET.q1 }}">
```

and

```
<a href="?page={{ query_naissance_list.previous_page_number }}&q1={{ request.GET.q1 }}">
```

or find another way to get this `q1` value

Comment: User writes a year in the field just above the array. `q1` corresponding to the value as variable. So, the array displays the query result to all objects which contain `date` as `q1` value and pagination lets me to show result page by page.

Comment: It works with your edit ! Thank you :) I had to specify the `q1` variable to each page. I thought it was automatical in my script.